# Confused about Pattern Recognition Network in Matlab Documentation

Tags: machine-learning, matlab

In the Matlab documentation for the Pattern Recognition Network (`patternnet()`), I am confused about a line of code in the documentation:

```
[x,t] = iris_dataset;
net = patternnet(10);
net = train(net,x,t);
view(net)
y = net(x);
perf = perform(net,t,y);
classes = vec2ind(y);
```

Why is `y = net(x)`?  So, I am assuming that `y` is the output vector, but why is it set to the column of the input vector, `x`?  I see that the net is the matrix containing the information from the `train()` function call, but why would it be asking for the inputs?

Reference: http://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ref/patternnet.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `y = net(x)` is the inference - using the trained model to predict `y` given a test input `x`. I suspect that the model is internally splitting the data of `x` in training, validation and test sub-sets, but keeping that only as index references. Thus it needs the input vector to pull the test sub-set out of it. See if the example [code](http://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/gs/classify-patterns-with-a-neural-network.html#f9-26645) makes better sense.

Comment: Thanks for the other example.  But what I don't understand is why it's being called an `output`, if it's the neural network's input?  Is `net(input)` returned an array that I'm not understanding?

Comment: While being trained, the NN is trying to "discover" a function `f(x)` such that `f(x_train) = t` with `t` being the labels. After the model is trained, the purpose of `f(x)` is to produce predictions. If `x_test` is the input, then `y = f(x_test)` is the output. I think the confusion comes from the vector `x` containing both `x_train` and `x_test` which have completely different purposes.